# Suggestion is not working for other namespace in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and I have a problem with suggestion when coding.
For example:
When I type "throw new NotImple", I expect that **NotImplementedException** is in the suggestion list but it is not.
It only appears when I have "using System" defined on top.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you very much !!

Comment: This behavior is by design; that type is in the `System` namespace.

Comment: type `throw new System.NotImple`

Comment: @SLaks : Is this the new behavior for Visual Studio 2013? Because when I see some video tutorials, the class is in the suggestion list even though he didn't need to add "using System". The line "using System" is added automatically (like Java).

Comment: All of the new file templates in every version of VS should include `using System;`.  How are you creating your files?

Comment: @Slaks: I see. Consider it as an example. So I have to remember the namespace where the class belongs? (I don't want that). And how the guy I mentioned above do it? Thanks.

Comment: What guy? Are you talking about a video? Since none of us know what video you're talking about, how can we tell you how "they guy" did it? As SLaks said, normally the `using System;` is in the template and so normally one need not do anything extra at all.

Comment: Normally when you start a new project with Visual Studio you choose a "template", such as "Windows Forms Application", or "WPF Application", or "Console Application", or "Class Library", etc., etc. You have apparently managed to start a new project without having selected a template along the way. Or done something else rather strange. In that case you can't blame Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's why some people spend additional money and get [JetBrains ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) or perhaps a similar extension. Even many video tutorials make use of it, but not always mention that fact at the beginning of the video.

[image: ReSharper suggesting exception]